# How can i execute the events in sequence in jquery AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: myurl,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#dialog-confirm').html(data);
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
    }
});
```

I want that second function in success executes after first one is complete. how can i do that

Comment: It **will** execute after the first one is complete.  What makes you think it doesn't do that? The "html()" function is synchronous.  Are you sure that "data" actually contains what you expect it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, because `.html` is synchronous.

If it's not doing that then we need more information.

Comment: I intially had #dialog-confirm div box not hidden , so it was showing data in there then stopped.it was not opening the dialog box but then i hide the div and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

$.when(// your first function).then(// your second function);
You can also do it with chaining 
    $('#dialog').html('something').dialog('open');