# How do I adjust the sequence of JavaScript events within a single function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can tell the browser to wait to start on function until after another is completed?

For example, in the following for loop, I'd like for contact() to fire and conclude, prior to moveForward() commencing.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($slugPace - 1); $i++ ) {
    contract();
    moveForward();
    reset();
};
```

I attempted using `$.when(// your first function).then(// your second function);` mentioned in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563508/how-can-i-execute-the-events-in-sequence-in-jquery-ajax-function), but the JS functions in the three listed functions continued to fire simultaneously.

Here is the code in total, if that helps:

```
    //Contracting the slug once:
    function contract(){
        $("#slug").animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            width: $slugThinner,
            height: $slugHigher,
        }, 250);
        $(".slugContainer").animate({
            marginLeft: $slugLeftMargin,
        }, 250);
    };

    //Extending the slug out and move him forward once:
    function moveForward(){
        $slugLeftMargin += $slugStepsLength;
        $("#slug").animate({
            marginTop: $slugMarginJS,
            width: $slugWide,
            height: $slugHigh,
        }, 250);
        $(".slugContainer").animate({
            marginLeft: $slugLeftMargin,
        }, 250);
    };

    function movement(){
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $slugStepsTotal; $i++ ) {
            contract();
            moveForward();
        };
    }

    function reset(){
        if ($slugLeftMargin > $screenWidth) {
            $slugLeftMargin = $slugWide * -1;
            $("#slug").stop().hide;
            $(".slugContainer").stop.css('margin-left',$slugLeftMargin);
            for ($i = 0; $i <= ($slugPace - 1); $i++ ) {
                contract();
                moveForward();
            };
        }
    }

    //Looping the contractions to move our little friend across the screen:
    $("#slug").click(function(){
        //alert('Slug width: ' + $slugWide + ', Slug height: ' + $slugHigh + ', Screen width: ' + $screenWidth + ', Slug steps total: ' + $slugStepsTotal + ', Slug higher: ' + $slugHigher + ', Slug thinner: ' + $slugThinner);
        //alert($slugStepsTotal);
        //alert('One step: ' + $slugStepsLength + '; Total steps: ' + $slugStepsTotal + '; Screen width: ' + $screenWidth);
        $("#slug").show();
        $(".clickMe").fadeOut(300);
        $.when(movement).then(reset());
    });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you can solve this with the Observer pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms, since you're using the `animate` method, you could do something with callbacks, say:

```
function contract(callback) {
    $("#slug").animate({
            marginTop: 0,
            width: $slugThinner,
            height: $slugHigher,
        }, 250);
     $(".slugContainer").animate({
            marginLeft: $slugLeftMargin,
     }, 250, function() {
       callback();
      }
    );
```

And you'd call contract like this:

```
contract(function(){ moveForward(); });
```

You can read-up a bit more about `animate` [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

That is the basic idea of what you need: callbacks.

Good luck mate!

Comment: No need to use anonymous functions as wrappers.  Just pass the function reference.  Ie, `.animate(..., 250, callback)` and `contract(callback)`

Comment: Thank you, Deleteman. I think you've just about nailed it. I believe I've set things up just as you recommend. However, I'm now getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. I made this the only statement in my while loop: `contract(moveForward());`. I began my function this way: `function contract(callback){`. And I ended the function with `}, 250, callback());`. `moveForward` is all syntactically correct, too - it works just fine when not used as a callback.  Can you see from this what I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, your porblem is this: `contract(moveForward());` you should have written: `contract(moveForward);` (minus the parenthesis for moveForward). On your code, you're calling the function moveForward when you call contract, and since that function doens't return anything, the callback is `undefined`. If you don't use the parenthesis, you're passing a reference to the function and that's what you'll use when you call `callback();`. Does it make any sence?

Comment: Yes! That worked wonderfully for getting everything in the correct sequence. Thank you very much.  Now I need to figure out how to break the animation sequence mid-stream with a button.  This looks like it's going to be very tricky, as I'm thinking all of the animation gets compiled, before you see any motion on the screen.  I'll probably have to compose another Stackoverflow question for that.  I'll post a link here, once I've posted.  As an aside, I'm new to Stackoverflow, and very stoked it's here.  Thank you for being one of the people that make it so awesome.

Comment: Glad to help.. and btw, to stop an animation, jQuery provides the `stop()` method. You can use that anytime you want to stop animations that have already started.